# Number with a lot decimals in pentaho cde table component

Tags: formatting, pentaho, pentaho-cde

i have 4 columns in a table of pentaho cde. the 1st column is a string the second and third column are numbers with a lot of decimals. i want this numbers in this format ###,## how can i do it in table component of pentahop cde.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the table’s Column formats property set those columns with format ‘%.2f’, and the others as ‘null’